# How Can I Play a Fighter Dual-Wielding Shields?

Tags: dnd-4e, fighter, shield

I'm rolling my very first D&D character. I'm trying to play a tank-type role in my group as a Dwarf Fighter. While looking through some forums I came across an image of an African warrior wielding 2 shields

[image: warrior wielding 2 shields]

Is this even a viable option in D&D?

What rules do I need to know when building a Dual-Shield Fighter and how can I increase my damage on top adding spikes to my shield?

---

*Here's the information I have so far:*

I'm pretty sure every basic attack I make will need to be a Dual Strike at-will attack so I can hit 2 enemies in the 1 action.

I know in 3.5e you can add spikes to a shield that increases your shield damage roll to 1d6.

I've also come across information about how preforming an attack with a shield can decrease it's AC bonus but that there may be a feat that can change this, I'm unsure about this though.

Comment: Your Requirements:
Wield 2 shields (spiked).
Use Dual-strike to hit 2 enemies.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Just out of curisoity, was this an actual fighting style, or was it more for training or demonstration?

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman I don't know about this specific picture, since nothing is given of its context, and I don't recognise the specific shield or dress styles or the stance the warrior is using, but in the general sense, yes, using two shields did exist as a real fighting style in at least one place that I remember reading about, and another that dual-wielded a weapon that could arguably be called a "shield", as it looked to western eyes more like a shield than a sword, even though it was mostly wielded more like the latter, and was designed to block like a shield in addition to attacking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Dual Shield fighter *is* possible, but is restrictive and fiddly.

First, when making high-concept stuff like this, it's critical to be aware of potential pitfalls of your character. Take a look at [this guide](https://www.enworld.org/threads/harder-than-a-rock-the-fighters-handbook-by-lorduskblade.469122/) to get a sense of the traps involved.

To realize this, my first preference would be to refluff some more "standard" version of the fighter into a double-shield fighter. Holding two shields does *nothing* for your defensive capabilities. But, with that said, the feats of superior proficiency "spiked shield" and midnight blade student make dual strike quite... interesting. You can "shield bash" two people a turn. Of course, the problem is in good positioning and *actually doing damage.* While entertaining, the dual strike fighter tends to be severely "one-trick pony"-ized.

As a first time player, I would instead look towards the [Knight](https://www.enworld.org/threads/death-before-dishonor-a-knights-guide-by-lorduskblade.469139/)-variant of fighter. There's less "fiddly" stuff, and the idea of a heavy shield + spiked shield can serve you quite well. It's also very *very* hard to go wrong with Dwarven Weapon Training, with a Heavy shield and "gauntlet axe" (if you want to fit your personal style) and just say the "gauntlet axe" is a razor-sharp shield.

Two shields as "important" only really comes into play with the [Snapping Tetsudo](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=650) Paragon Path, a relatively uninspiring choice, unfortunately. To be fair, Dragon Magazine 385 has a significant number of "shield-as-weapon" choices, but few of them require *two* shields. All that being said, I would still go with knight + dwarven weapon training, and either pretend a hammer or an axe was a shield, depending if you want to be bashy or slicy. The mechanics fit better, and the thematic imagery can be just as vivid.

Comment: If you want to be creative on a roleplay side, you can have your character _pretend_ he's wielding two shields, despite one is an actual weapon. Could be much fun, if done well.

Comment: The link to "this guide" is (predictably; thank you , WotC!) dead. Can you find another location for it or footnote in a few-sentence summary?

Comment: @nitsua60: I've updated the guide links to versions of those same guides hosted on ENWorld.

Answer (score -4):

What if it was two pointy shields?
The idea is to have a strong defense and a nice damage, dealing a half-stab/falf-blunt damage, not only bashing using the shields face, being able to still do great damage using Holy Smite.
A "weapon" that, if someone attacks you from the rear while you're attaking someone, you could just retract your arm and simply block it. A warrior who focus on defense and can deal a nice damage when given the chance.

[image: That's a example I (poorlly)made on Photoshop]

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE.  Are you familiar with D&D 4th Edition?  That's the game system the person was asking about.  Simply generating ideas isn't what an SE Q&A site aims to do.  The aim is to solve a problem as stated in the question.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get a better idea for what this format prefers.  (This isn't a discussion forum).  Thanks for joining in, and happy gaming.  The down votes are a sign that users do not find the answer helpful.    If you can demonstrate how what you are proposing would fit into D&D 4th edition, that would be a great help.